# Can you codesign a Mac OS X App outside of Xcode and have Gatekeeper accept it?

Tags: code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I have an application (installer, actually) that was built outside of Xcode which I have codesigned using the `codesign` utility, but when I try to install it after downloading the signed app, Gatekeeper complains that it comes from an unidentified developer.  I have tried using the "3rd Party Mac Developer:..." identity, as well as my own "Mac Developer:..." identity; same result in either case.  `codesign` (as far as I can tell) says all is well, so I'm thinking I'm either using the wrong identity (in which case my question is what I should use/make-to-use instead) or the signature is fine, but there is something that needs to be done w/ my developer account (in which case my question is what might that be).

Comment: This appears to be the original question about this topic and subsequently cross-posting to SU.SE and AD.SE was a bad idea. If you feel your question is in the wrong place then please flag for a mod to migrate. Thanks.

Comment: What is SE?  I did post to SU (Super User) and AD (Ask Different), but nowhere else.

Comment: SE == Stack Exchange. SuperUser and Ask Different are all sites in the same Q&A network so you should only ask your question **one** of the sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple, and verified by me :), there is another set of identities specifically for signing apps to satisfy the intermediate security setting in Gatekeeper, but only a Team's Agent can get, which is why I wasn't getting them.  My agent got them, I used them, and Gatekeeper is happy.